# Using Date Picker to get the search result with Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

**[Modified Question]**

Below is the code to search the data with the Data Picker.

**in before /head**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        startDate: '01-10-2017',
       onSelect: function (dateText) {
         $("#datepicker_to").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
       }
    });
    $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        endDate: '01-11-2017',
    });
</script>
```

**Laravel-Collective code**

```
 {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form', 'method' => 'get', 'url' => url('/login_history_search'))) !!} 
 {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_from', ['id' => 'datepicker_from']) }}
 {{ Form::input('text', 'datepicker_to', ['id' => 'datepicker_to']) }} 
 {!! Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!} 
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function login_history_search(Request $request) 
  { 
  $histories = DB::table('loginhistories')
  ->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->orWhere('created_at','<=', Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->format('Y-m-d')) 
  ->get(); 
  return view('profiles.login_histories', ['histories' => $histories]); 
  }
```

**loginhistories table structure**

[image]

Finally, the query result was same as all data.
Let me know how to modify code for get the correct search result from server.

Comment: Can you add the route please ??

Comment: Ok just add the routes to see, because MethodNotAllowedHttpException is related to them :)

Comment: @Maraboc, I think my approach is wrong.
The DateRange Picker does not seem to be able to query in my database.
The reason is that the date values stored in the DataRange and the server are different from each other. Is it right? if right, then I just try to adjust  "Date Picker" :)

Comment: I don't think so because the problem probablly is that in the route you expect a GET request bau in the form it's a POST request, so change in the routes file then add a parameter here `login_history_search(Request $request)` then remove `if(!isset($_GET['daterange']) ){` then test ;)

Comment: @Maraboc, ok, then I have to modify correct DB:raw() query.:) thx!!

Comment: @Maraboc, I rewrote question.. could you help me? :)

Comment: @Maraboc, the dd() result was null, so I think collective query was wrong. :(

Comment: Check the update in the answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157000/discussion-between-magnetic-and-maraboc).

Answer (score 0):

In the controller yu should use the request to get the input text values like this :

```
public function login_history_search(Request $request)
{
    $daterange = 
    $histories = DB::table('loginhistories')
    ->where('last_login_at', '>=', $request->input('daterange_from'))
    ->orwhere('last_logout_at', '<=', $request->input('daterange_to'))
    ->get();
    dd(request($histories));
    return view('profiles.login_histories', ['histories' => $histories]);
}
```

Comment: Hi ;) {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form')) !!}
{{ Form::input('text', 'daterange', "01/10/2017 - 01/11/2017", ['id' => 'datepicker']) }}
{!! Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
How to use submit button for get the search result in the code? always many thanks.

Comment: it's little bit difficulty to make controller for get the input date range value.:(

Comment: What is the returned value of  `dd(request('daterange'));` in the controller ? because i never used this datepicker :p

Comment: I found this useful link 
 http://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html   but how can I adjust into the Laravel with collective.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally, I got the correct result by below code. :) thanks @Maraboc!!**

The core idea was using whereBetween query builder.

```
public function login_history_search(Request $request) 
  { 
  $histories = DB::table('loginhistories') 
  ->whereBetween('last_login_at', array(
    (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->format('Y-m-d')),
    (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->format('Y-m-d'))
    )
   ) 
  ->get();
  return view('profiles.login_histories', ['histories' => $histories]); 
  }
```